# Is it possible to run hMailServer on Azure?

Tags: email, azure

Is it possible to run hMailServer on Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. Check for example [this thread](http://www.hmailserver.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=18014) and [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azure_Services_Platform). Azure applications must be specifically built for Azure.

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy mail server on Azure such as Zimbra or hMail, but perhaps you will get problem with Reverse DNS because Azure still don't have this feature. Some mail server need ptr record, if you can't provide the information, the mail will be rejected or flagged as spam. But if you send the mail to gmail, outlook, or yahoo it won't be a problem.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.